# Query with sub-results from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two database tables:

```
`membership_members` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

`membership_payments` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `member` (`member`)
)
```

I wish to list all the members, and for each of them I would like to show the list of all the payments by that member. The `membership_payments.member` column is a foreign key `membership_members.id` (this is MySQL so I cannot explicitly specify a foreign key). Notice that I do want to list a member even if he doesn't have any payments.

So something like:

```
* John Smith
    - 2012-05-06 $100
    - 2012-01-02 $100
* Brian Jones

* Mike Jackson
    - 2012-09-02 $50
```

I have tried with this query:

```
SELECT id, name, active, date, amount
FROM `membership_members`,
     `membership_payments`
WHERE membership_members.id = member
```

This of course gives me tha data I need, but not exactly how I need it as it returns a row for each payment. That means that I later have to group the rows (in PHP) by member id so that I don't list a member multiple times. I *can* do that, but I believe that it would be easier and faster to do it in SQL. Also, this query only gives me users which have payments with their id.

I feel that this should be simple, but last time I did anything but the most simple stuff in SQL was 6-7 years ago.

**EDIT:**
`LEFT OUTER JOIN` suggested in one of the answers solves the issue with the "missing" members. But what is the best way of grouping results by member IDs? I know there is a `GROUP BY` clause, but it doesn't give me all the payments for the given member, only one. I suppose I can run a new payments query for each member, but I fear this would be very inefficient (we have around 300-400 members).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to `JOIN` the two tables based on referencing key columns.

```
SELECT id, name, active, date, amount
FROM membership_members
    LEFT OUTER JOIN membership_payments 
        ON membership_members.id = membership_payments.member;
```

I chose `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so that the members without payments are also shown.

For more info on joins check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

**EDIT**

Use `ORDER BY membership_members.id` to get records ordered by a certain column.
Grouping does not behave like sorting. `GROUPING` **merges** all records by the column you provided. `ORDER BY` **sorts**

Comment: Yes, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` does the trick with the "missing" members, and it is coming back to me now :) But please see my edit in the question.

Comment: Use `ORDER BY` to get all the records for one member nicely together. `ORDER BY membership_members.id`

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that. I guess there is no easy way to avoid doing some grouping in PHP to present the data the way I wish.

Comment: If you order them by ID, you can easily loop through the records in PHP and handle the previousrecord.member_id != currentrecord.member_id and show the name of the member ;-) But that's actually a different question hehe

Comment: That was the question I was trying to ask :) I just assumed there was an easy way to accomplish this with SQL. I guess I'll have to smack it with a PHP hammer after all ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `GROUP_CONCAT` MySQL clause.

[`Example`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

**OR**

You can use `CONCAT`.

**Example**

```
SELECT CONCAT(`membership_payments.date`, ' ', `membership_payments.amount`) 
   FROM `membership_members`
 LEFT OUTER JOIN membership_payments 
    ON membership_members.id = membership_payments.member;
```

Comment: that would be `GROUP_CONCAT` :) Small typo there.

Comment: @UwConcept so that does not mean down-vote...even you can edit it too....thats rediculos man..

Comment: Hehe relax man, I didn't downvote. I just commented so you could improve your post that's all. No need for prejudice.

Comment: what makes you think the op wants `GROUP_CONCAT()`?

Comment: @JW in question OP said result like `- 2012-05-06 $100 - 2012-01-02 $100`

Comment: Hi. I may not have been clear enough in my question, but my issue was not getting the values in a certain format (I present the data in HTML) but rather to get the data I need.

Comment: @NobleK if format is not issue then remove concat code and just add * and use that query

Answer (score 1):

use `LEFT JOIN`

basically, what you are doing now is an `INNER JOIN`. `INNER JOIN` only displays a records if it has atleast one record on each table. But `LEFT JOIN` operates differently. It displays all records on the *Lefthand side* table whether it has matching record or not on the *righthand side* table.

```
SELECT  id, name, active, date, amount
FROM    `membership_members` a
        LEFT JOIN `membership_payments` b
            ON a.ID = b.member
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you for the useful link about SQL joins. It is sort of coming back to me now :) But I thing that a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` might be the correct one in my case.

Comment: @NobleK `OUTER` is optional keyword.

Comment: Funny, when I ran your code earlier I didn't get the members without payments. I must have done/seen something wrong. It **does** work without `OUTER`. Sorry about that.